# Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/#########' is not defined in the template

Tags: azure, botframework

Hi I am trying to deploy an Azure bot, however I am receiving an error when I try command on Azure Powershell Windows:

```
az deployment create --template-file "./template-with-new-rg.json" --location "#####" --parameters appId="#####" appSecret="#####" botId="#####" botSku=## newAppServicePlanName="#####" newWebAppName="#####" groupName="#####"  groupLocation="#####" newAppServicePlanLocation="#####" --name "#####"
```

Error below:

```
Azure Error: InvalidTemplate
Message: Deployment template validation failed: 'The resource 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/#########' is not defined in the template. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template for usage details.'.
Additional Information:
        Type: TemplateViolation
        Info: {
            "lineNumber": 0,
            "linePosition": 0,
            "path": ""
        }
```

Template link below

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxdkbedl2a6sswu/template-with-new-rg.json?dl=0

Comment: If you can post the ARM template, it would help with finding the solution. Based on the message, it sounds like there is a dependency listed for a serverFarm (App Service Plan) resource that’s missing from the template

Comment: Hi Alex i have added the template on the original question.

Comment: This template is not accessible.

Comment: Hi Jagrati, template link updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: As of 1 October 2020, the ARM templates have been updated. Please use a current ARM template to attempt to deploy.

This is a currently (as of 10 August 2020) ongoing issue with deployment. For example, the issue raised [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/2583) is the same and links to another issue tracking it yet again. The bot framework  team is working on a fix at the moment.

The work around is to manually create your empty resource group on Azure, and then run the command to deploy-to-existing-RG instead of to a new one.

I am monitoring the progress of the fix, and will update this answer as soon as a fix is released.

Comment: Hi JJ, thanks for the information. I have now created an empty "Resource group" on Azure. And then ran "az" deployment command with template-with-preexisting-rg.json however I am receiving Resource not found error

Comment: "code": "ResourceNotFound",
    "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/serverFarms/######' under resource group '<null>' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix"
  }
}

Comment: Managed to deploy by removing dependsOn... Thanks! JJ.

Comment: This workaround is not working for me